# Rendered attribute in xhtml

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, rendered-attribute

Below is my code in xhtml:

```
<p:row rendered="#{abcBean.xyzmethod}">
```

In my bean:

```
public boolean xyzmethod(){
   String def = "ghi";
   if(!def.equal("ghi"){
       return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

My requirement is, I don't want to display this row if xyzmethod returns false. But I am getting error while loading xhtml as : javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:abcBean does not have the property 'xyzmethod'.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help!

Comment: Never used primefaces, but I would think it would be `#{abcBean.xyzmethod()}` since it's a method and not a property.

Comment: Awwwww! Simple coding mistake. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: You're welcome! I'll go ahead and add my comment as an answer.

Comment: it is not PF related, but JSF

Answer (score 0):

It should be `#{abcBean.xyzmethod()}` (with parens) since it's a method and not a property.